# Any adverse effects of adding apply_filters to a function?

Tags: functions, child-theme, filters

I'm going back through my older WordPress theme and making the functions filterable and also adding the function_exists checks. Is there anything I'm not thinking about that this may cause problems with existing code?

```
// Dummy function
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_func' )) {
    function custom_func() {
        $output = "Something Awesome";
        return apply_filters('custom_func', $output);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would add prefixes, as a plugin developer may have functions with the same name or filters with the same name, e.g. `mytheme_`

Comment: Agreed. (My example wasn't great) I am just wondering of any downsides of adding the apply_filters to every custom function to make the themes more flexible down the road.